# Finding conditional expectation and conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

Let $\xi $ be a random variable in $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ distributed according to $\mathrm{Unif}\{-2,...,3\}$. Hence, 
$$\mathbb{P}(\xi = -2) = \mathbb{P}(\xi = -1) =\mathbb{P}(\xi = 0) =\mathbb{P}(\xi = 1) =\mathbb{P}(\xi = 2) =\mathbb{P}(\xi = 3) =1/6$$
Now let $\mathcal{D}=\{D_1,D_2,D_3\}$ where $D_1=\{\xi<0\}$ $D_2=\{\xi \in [0,2]\}$ $D_3=\{ \xi >2 \}$.

I need to find:

1) $\mathbb{E}(\xi^2|\mathcal{D})$ (The conditional expectation).

2) $\mathbb{P}(\xi<1|\mathcal{D})$.

I am not sure, but I think that for 1) I should use formula $\mathbb{E}(\xi^2 |\mathcal{D})(\omega)= \sum_{i} \frac{\mathbb{E}(\xi^2 \mathbf{1}_{D_i)}}{\mathbb{P}(D_i)} \mathbf{1}_{D_i} (\omega) $. But how should I use it?

Comment: In your original distribution, you have six possible outcomes, -1 to 3, each "equally likely".  Restricting to $D_1$, "< 0", means that we are restricting to 2 outcomes, -2 and -1, still equally likely.  Restricting to $D_1$, the probabilities of -2 and of -1 are both 1/2 and the expected value is (1/2)(-1)+ (1/2)(-2)= -1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $\mathbb E[\xi^2\mid\mathcal D]$ denotes the same as $\mathbb E[\xi^2\mid\mathcal\sigma(\mathcal D)]$

---

$\mathbb{E}\left[\xi^{2}\mid\mathcal{D}\right]$ is measurable wrt
$\sigma\left(\mathcal{D}\right)$ implying here the existence of coefficients
$a,b,c$ with $$\mathbb{E}\left[\xi^{2}\mid\mathcal{D}\right]=a\mathbf{1}_{\xi<0}+b\mathbf{1}_{0\leq\xi\leq2}+c\mathbf{1}_{\xi>2}\tag1$$

Secondly we have the equalities: $$\mathbb{E}\left[\xi^{2}\mathbf{1}_{D}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[\xi^{2}\mid\mathcal{D}\right]\mathbf{1}_{D}\right]\text{ for every }D\in\sigma\left(\mathcal{D}\right)\tag2$$

Substituting $\left(1\right)$ in $(2)$ we find for  $D=\{\xi<0\}$, $\{0\leq\xi\leq2\}$ and $\{\xi>2\}$:

- $\mathbb{E}\left[\xi^{2}\mathbf{1}_{\xi<0}\right]=aP\left(\xi<0\right)$
- $\mathbb{E}\left[\xi^{2}\mathbf{1}_{0\leq\xi\leq2}\right]=bP\left(0\leq\xi\leq2\right)$
- $\mathbb{E}\left[\xi^{2}\mathbf{1}_{\xi>2}\right]=cP\left(\xi>2\right)$

Or equivalently

- $a=\mathbb{E}\left[\xi^{2}\mid\xi<0\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left(-2\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(-1\right)^{2}=\frac{5}{2}$
- $b=\mathbb{E}\left[\xi^{2}\mid0\leq\xi\leq2\right]=\frac{1}{3}0^{2}+\frac{1}{3}1^{2}+\frac{1}{3}2^{2}=\frac{5}{3}$
- $c=\mathbb{E}\left[\xi^{2}\mid\xi>2\right]=3^{2}=9$.

So we end up with: $$\mathbb{E}\left[\xi^{2}\mid\mathcal{D}\right]=\frac{5}{2}\mathbf{1}_{\xi<0}+\frac{5}{3}\mathbf{1}_{0\leq\xi\leq2}+9\mathbf{1}_{\xi>2}$$

---

**edit**:

Observe that $\mathbb P(\xi<1\mid\mathcal D)=\mathbb E(\mathbf1_{\xi<1}\mid\mathcal D)$.

We can find it exactly as above if we replace $\xi^2$ there by $\mathbf1_{\xi<1}$:

- $\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf1_{\xi<1}\mathbf{1}_{\xi<0}\right]=aP\left(\xi<0\right)$
- $\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf1_{\xi<1}\mathbf{1}_{0\leq\xi\leq2}\right]=bP\left(0\leq\xi\leq2\right)$
- $\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf1_{\xi<1}\mathbf{1}_{\xi>2}\right]=cP\left(\xi>2\right)$

Or equivalently:

- $a=\mathbb P(\xi<1\mid\xi<0)=1$
- $b=\mathbb P(\xi<1\mid0\leq\xi\leq2)=\frac13$
- $c=\mathbb P(\xi<1\mid \xi>2)=0$

So we end up with: $$\mathbb{P}\left[\xi<1\mid\mathcal{D}\right]=\mathbf{1}_{\xi<0}+\frac{1}{3}\mathbf{1}_{0\leq\xi\leq2}$$

Comment: can you show me and second part?

Comment: Can you be more precise: what exactly is the second part in your view?

Comment: can you show how to find  $\mathbb{P}(\xi<1|\mathcal{D})$?

Comment: Exactly the same route. See my edit.

Answer (score -1):

First, we define the underlying probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P}) := (\{-2,...,3\}, 2^{\{-2,...,3\}}, \mathrm{Unif}\{-2,...,3\})$. $\xi$ is a random variable from $\Omega$ into itself, say $\xi \equiv \mathrm{id}_\Omega$. Hence, $\xi(\omega) = \omega$.
Note that $\mathbb{E}[\xi^2|\mathcal{D}]$ is also a random variable, from $\Omega$ into itself. Hence, we need to compute its value (in principal) for every $\omega \in \Omega$. Also note that the outcome really depends on the definition of $\xi$ above. Only the distribution of $\mathbb{E}[\xi^2|\mathcal{D}]$ is unique.
We can now just apply the formula:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\xi^2|\mathcal{D}](-2) &= \frac{(-2)^2 \cdot 1/6 + (-1)^2 \cdot 1/6}{1/3} = 2.5\\
\mathbb{E}[\xi^2|\mathcal{D}](-1) &= \frac{(-2)^2 \cdot 1/6 + (-1)^2 \cdot 1/6}{1/3} = 2.5\\
\mathbb{E}[\xi^2|\mathcal{D}](0) &= \frac{0^2 \cdot 1/6 + 1^2 \cdot 1/6 + 2^2 \cdot 1/6}{1/2} = 5/3\\
\mathbb{E}[\xi^2|\mathcal{D}](1) &= \frac{0^2 \cdot 1/6 + 1^2 \cdot 1/6 + 2^2 \cdot 1/6}{1/2} = 5/3\\
\mathbb{E}[\xi^2|\mathcal{D}](2) &= \frac{0^2 \cdot 1/6 + 1^2 \cdot 1/6 + 2^2 \cdot 1/6}{1/2} = 5/3\\
\mathbb{E}[\xi^2|\mathcal{D}](3) &= \frac{3^2 \cdot 1/6}{1/6} = 9.
\end{align}
If I didn't do any mistakes, this should be the correct conditional expectation, given the modelling of $\xi$.
The second example you can probably solve yourself, remember that $\mathbb{P}(\xi < 1|\mathcal{D} ) = \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\xi < 1}|\mathcal{D}]$.

Comment: Sorry but it is absolutely not necessary to specify the probability space. For every probability space on which $\xi$ is defined, $E(\xi\mid\mathcal{D})=\sum\limits_ix_i\mathbf 1_{D_i}$ for some numbers $(x_i)$ that are the same for every probability space such that $\xi$ has the correct distribution.

Comment: So can I say that $\mathbb{E} (\xi^2|\mathcal{D}) =13,167$?

Comment: @Did True. To determine the distribution of that conditional expectation, it should be not necessary. I found it easier to explain it like this, when using the formula above that distinguishes $\xi$ and $\omega$.

Comment: @Atstovas No. This conditional expectation is a random variable and therefore a function of $\Omega$. It is (in general) not a deterministic value. Maybe, you want to check up on the definition in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-σ-algebra

Comment: @Jonas can you show me also and second example?